# Multiple UIAlertViews in the same view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uialertview

I have two UIAlertViews with ok/cancel buttons.

I catch the user response by:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

The question I'm having is, **which alertView is currently open?**
I have different actions to do when clicking ok/cancel on each one...

Comment: Use the .tag property to differentiate.

[Here is the question you asked][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346418/uialertviewdelegate-and-more-alert-windows

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have several options:

- Use ivars. When creating the alert view:

  ```
  myFirstAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWith...];
  [myFirstAlertView show];
  // similarly for the other alert view(s).
  ```

  And in the delegate method:

  ```
  - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
      if (alertView == myFirstAlertView) {
          // do something.
      } else if (alertView == mySecondAlertView) {
          // do something else.
      }
  }
  ```
- Use the `tag` property of `UIView`:

  ```
  #define kFirstAlertViewTag 1
  #define kSecondAlertViewTag 2
  ```

  ```
  UIAlertView *firstAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWith...];
  firstAlertView.tag = kFirstAlertViewTag;
  [firstAlertView show];
  // similarly for the other alert view(s).
  ```

  ```
  - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
      switch (alertView.tag) {
          case kFirstAlertViewTag:
              // do something;
              break;
          case kSecondAlertViewTag:
              // do something else
              break;
      }
  }
  ```
- Subclass `UIAlertView` and add a `userInfo` property. This way you can add an identifier to your alert views.

  ```
  @interface MyAlertView : UIAlertView
  @property (nonatomic) id userInfo;
  @end
  ```

  ```
  myFirstAlertView = [[MyAlertView alloc] initWith...];
  myFirstAlertView.userInfo = firstUserInfo;
  [myFirstAlertView show];
  // similarly for the other alert view(s).
  ```

  ```
  - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
      if (alertView.userInfo == firstUserInfo) {
          // do something.
      } else if (alertView.userInfo == secondUserInfo) {
          // do something else.
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

`UIAlertView` is a `UIView` subclass so you can use its `tag` property for identification. So when you create alert view set its tag value and then you will be able to do the following:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
   if (alertView.tag == kFirstAlertTag){
      // First alert
   }
   if (alertView.tag == kSecondAlertTag){
      // First alert
   }
}
```