# how to move on 2 different page using 2 different alert view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uialertview

On my app there is a password reset page. if the textfield is blank and the user hits the submit it generates an alert with title : **Invalid input** however when user puts the password and clicks on submit he gets a different alert with title : **password changed**. when user clicks on ok of password changed alert he should gets directed to the different page but when he clicks on ok of invalid input alert he should stay on the same page.In order to redirect to the differen page I am using the method below

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertViewclickedButtonAtIndex(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

so,whenever user clicks on ok of any alert it's redirecting the user to the different page. How can I differentiate between both alert's ok button?

Comment: give tag to UIAlertView for differentiate both alert .

Comment: try these link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731460/multiple-uialertviews-in-the-same-view?rq=1

Comment: https://github.com/ryanmaxwell/UIAlertView-Blocks try This , you can deal with every alert with out listing to delegate of uialertview

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing for iOS 8 or later, good news: You can **use UIAlertController instead**, which solves this problem by its design. And if you are creating a new app now, with iOS 9 out, I'd seriously consider dropping support for iOS 7.

If you must support iOS 7, you can handle this in a couple different ways:

1) Add a class property to keep track of which alert view you last showed; in the click handler check that value and respond appropriately. This is the quick and dirty fix.

2) Create a little utility class that implements the UIAlertViewDelegate protocol. Create 2 objects of that class. Use one object for each alertview that you create. Have that class call back into code in your viewcontroller. You can use this utility class in the future when you need to do this again.